# Starting Apache 2 at boot on Mac OS X Server 10.6

Tags: apache-2.2, mac-osx, launchd

Having compiled, installed and configured Apache 2.2.15 on Mac OS X Server 10.6, all went fine. The server is running fine when started manually, no configuration problems.

Then i added a launchd system wide daemon (in /Library/LaunchDaemons/), loaded it and rebooted. Again this seems to work fine.

But Apache doesn't start at boot due to a problem with mod_unique_id, i guess. Here is the apache error log entry:

`[Tue Jun 29 09:01:29 2010] [alert] (EAI 8)nodename nor servname provided, or not known: mod_unique_id: unable to find IPv4 address of "my.server.net"
Configuration Failed`

It seems to me that launchd is firing the job too early in the boot process, at a time when reverse DNS lookup isn't done or properly propagated. If i start Apache manually via ssh, it starts without errors. (The server has a static IP with a fully qualified domain name set.)

Here is some lines out of my system.log:

```
Jun 29 09:01:29 org.apache.httpd[88]: httpd: apr_sockaddr_info_get() failed for my.server.com
Jun 29 09:01:29 org.apache.httpd[88]: httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.0.1 for ServerName
Jun 29 09:01:29 emond[78]: SetUpLogs: uid = 0 gid = 0
Jun 29 09:01:29 emond[78]: SetUpLogs: opening /Library/Logs/EventMonitor/EventMonitor.error.log
Jun 29 09:01:29 sandboxd[100]: kadmind(54) deny network-bind 0.0.0.0:654
Jun 29 09:01:29 sandboxd[100]: kadmind(54) deny network-bind 0.0.0.0:0
Jun 29 09:01:30 loginwindow: Login Window Application Started
Jun 29 09:01:30 com.apple.launchd (org.apache.httpd): Exited with exit code: 1
Jun 29 09:01:30 configd: network configuration changed.
```

The logs here are pretty clear, Apache is launched and fail to start right before the network is configured with a valid IP and DNS name. But this isn't consistent, in an other boot, the network configuration is done first, but the problem persists.

I tried to set the `ServerName` variable in httpd.conf to either the server's IP or FQDN, didn't helped.

I am a little lost, that's why i came here. Many searches on the net didn't helped me either.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can tell launchd to respawn the daemon if it crashes by adding something like this:

```
<key>KeepAlive</key>
<true/>
```

to the launchd .plist file.  Note: make sure you're running httpd with the `-D FOREGROUND` option so launchd can track its state properly, i.e. you should be running it like this:

```
<key>ProgramArguments</key>
<array>
    <string>/path/to/httpd</string>
    <string>-D</string>
    <string>FOREGROUND</string>
</array>
```

Also, you might want to change the item's label (and filename) to something other than org.apache.httpd; there's already a daemon by that label in /System/Library/LaunchDaemons, and I'm not sure if there's a possibility of a label conflict.